# What resources should I use with this REST implementation?

Tags: rest

I have a couple of web service calls that I can't think of a good way to do with REST - they feel like 'doing' methods rather than data manipulation.

One is just basically saying to the server "resend a confirmation e-mail to user xyz", so in SOAP it might be `ResendConfirmationEmail(user)`.  How could this be implemented in REST; what resource name should be used in the URI?

Another is one where we initialize the database with some dummy data and return its resulting tables and their row counts, so in SOAP it might be `InitializeDatabase()`.  Again, what should the URI look like in REST, and could this still be done as one call (do initialize, and return the database summary info) or would it have to be broken into two calls (one for initialize, one for get database summary info)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Resending (or sending for that matter) is not an idempotent operation.  This is an immediate indication for `POST`.  As for a URI, I would recommend something along the lines of

   ```
   POST /user/1234/mailbox
   ```

   If you really wanted to go above and beyond, and your app did some sort of internal logging or had an interface to your mail queue, it might also be nice to send a `GET` request to the newly created resource (e.g. `GET /user/1234/mailbox/<EMAIL ID>` and see the status of the email).  This is clearly a bells-and-whistle feature, however it gets you thinking in the RESTful mindset of resources, even in seemingly atypical situations.
2. Unlike #1, initializing a DB would be considered idempotent, but obviously unsafe.  `PUT` is the natural candidate.  As [Mr. Fielding himself *put* it](http://www.imc.org/atom-protocol/mail-archive/msg05425.html), PUT does not necessarily mean store something.  This is an example of that.  As for the URI, I would recommend one that identifies your system or app.   Maybe something like `/my-app-name` or something generic like `/conf` or `/system`.  One could even argue using `/`.  You could even pass config options in the body of the `PUT` request.

   As for getting the status of the system, I would recommend just making that a separate `GET` request to the same URI, however I can't think of why you also wouldn't just be able to include this same summary as part of the `PUT` response.

   *Side note: with something this unsafe, you definitely want to make sure you have a solid auth layer in place*.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Could you expand a little on PUTting to `/my-app-name`?  How would you suggest I indicate to the service that I want to reset the database as opposed to doing some other operation for that application?

Comment: So in that case, I guess I'd treat each "configuration" or "service" as a resource.  You could make it a bit more specific like `/my-app-name/db`, or even just `/service/db` or `/conf/db`.  That way you could also manage other services related to the app.  A RESTful app that is itself managed RESTfully is a pretty sweet thing.

Comment: I understand the idea of mapping a URI to the notion of the database - what I mean is, what exactly am I PUTting to that URI?  Not the contents of the DB, because I just want to tell it "initialize the DB", and not actually give the dummy data.

Comment: Ah.  Ultimately it's up to you.  Could be nothing at all (nothing wrong about a PUT with an empty body).  E.g. if you want your app to automatically interpret a `PUT` to `/services/db` to mean initialize the DB, then that's fine.  My suggestion about PUTting data, would moreso be for configuration tweaks to the init process (e.g. init the DB with a different ENGINE or something).